# Instantiating a Multimap with a set?

Tags: java, multimap

I have a `Set<String> setOfStrings`, and I want to place every string from the set into a MultiMap where each String in the set is its own key, and the corresponding value of each key is null. I could, of course, do this iteratively with:

```
Multimap multimap = HashMultimap.create();
for (String url : setOfStrings) {
    multimap.put(url, null);
}
```

However, is there any more shorthand/concise way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of java ?

Comment: What multimap are you using?  Your own code? Guava?

Comment: Google Commons Multimap, and Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

- `HashMultiMap` has no constructors
- there is no `create` method that takes a set
- `create(MultiMap)` in this case only adds a layer of indirection
- none of the methods that return other `Collection` views (`asMap`, `entries`, `keys`, `keySet`, `values`) support `add` or `put` operations

I'd say you have the best solution.